# Como diferenciar artigo indefinido de numeral?

Tags: números, substantivos

Existem expressões em que tenho dúvidas sobre a palavra *um* ou *uns*, pois ela pode ser artigo ou numeral.

> Exemplos:
>   (1) O Brasil deu *um* passo adiante para resolver o problema.
>   (2) O Brasil deu apenas *um* passo adiante para resolver o problema.

No exemplo (1) é artigo e no exemplo (2) é numeral?

Como diferenciar artigo indefinido de numeral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja:

> (1)     O Brasil deu um *(artigo indefinido)* passo adiante para resolver o problema.
>
> (2)     O Brasil deu apenas *(advérbio)* um *(numeral)* passo adiante para resolver o problema.

**Por que?**

O sentido de *“um passo”* não é indicar a quantidade de passos dados, mas de apontar que um ato necessário ocorreu, a conduta exigida foi efetuada. O contexto, portanto, permite inferir que não se concentra, a assertiva, em um número reduzido de passos.

Mas quando se enfatiza a quantidade (neste caso foi utilizado o advérbio *‘apenas’* para enfatizar/dar exclusividade ao ato), trata-se de um numeral.

Segue a [explicação do Professor Paulo Hernandes](http://www.paulohernandes.pro.br/dicas/001/dica159.html) abaixo:

[image]

Comment: É duvidosa essa do Prof Hernandes que *estamos preparando relatório* é melhor que *estamos preparando um relatório*. Para não falar em suprimir o artigo indefinido em *um dia destes vou à praia; era uma vez um gato maltês*. Por alguma razão o artigo indefinido existe.

Comment: Para que essa regra gramatical tenha validade a primeira frase tem de significar um avanço, e a segunda frase tem de significar partes de um processo; caso contrário, você pode trocar 'O Brasil deu um passo' e 'O Brasil deu apenas um passo' por 'O Brasil deu 1 passo' e 'O Brasil deu apenas 1 passo', e ainda 'O Brasil deu outro passo' e 'O Brasil deu apenas outro passo'; pois o 'um' funcionaria nessas frases como numeral ao contar os passos, e como elemento de indefinição quando se omite qual passo foi tomado.

Answer (score 0):

O plural de um (numeral) é dois (três, quatro, trezentos e cinquenta e sete, etc). O plural de um (artigo) é uns.

No caso,

*O Brasil deu uns passos à frente para resolver o problema.*

*O Brasil deu apenas dois passos à frente para resolver o problema.*

Aqui, na verdade, o advérbio "apenas" é introduzido para eliminar a ambiguidade. Sem ele, o "um" poderia ser tanto numeral quanto artigo (pois *O Brasil deu dois passos à frente para resolver o problema* também é uma construção bem natural). Que é o "apenas" quem cumpre esse papel pode ser observado se mudamos a sua posição:

*O Brasil apenas deu um passo à frente para resolver o problema.* - em que o "um" volta a ser facilmente interpretado como artigo.